Condition on conserved quantities to escape Kerr black hole
For a classical two-body gravitational system, we can easily check whether the trajectory is bounded by calculating the energy. If the energy is larger than a threshold $E > E_0$ (and if they are not directly running into each other, which requires precise lineup so we might as well ignore this), the two bodies are guaranteed to escape.
For a test mass orbiting a Kerr black hole, there are also four conserved quantites. Having $E > E_0$ is of course a necessary condition, but it is not sufficient: consider shooting a fast particle from the north into the black hole. If the velocity is close to radial, then it will always pass through the event horizon and can't escape, but its energy can be made arbitrarily large. Is there an easy condition on the conserved quantities $$m = \sqrt{-p_\mu p^\mu}, E = p_t, L = p_\theta$$ and Carter's constant to see if the particle will eventually escape?
Perhaps if we analytically extend the spacetime, the fast particles will pass through the singularity ring and escape into another asymptotically flat region when $E > E_0$? In that case, the condition on energy might still be a sufficient condition, but we can't guarantee which region it escapes into. This question can also be generalized to a charged particle orbiting a charged black hole.

That's already the case with Schwarzschild where a photon on a radial trajectory can escape above r=2, but a photon on a tangential path will not escape below the photon sphere at r=3.
